# How to parse JSON when response is in dictionary format?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I get HTTP response as below from a API call. All I would need is to store names in an array.

```
{
  "results":[
             {"name":"First","venue":{"zip":"90405","country":"US"},"desc":"1D"},
             {"name":"Second","venue":{"zip":"89065","country":"US"},"desc":"2D"},
             {"name":"Third","venue":{"zip":"92352","country":"US"},"desc":"3D"}
            ],
  "meta":{"next":"xxxx","url":"yyyy"}
}
```

I wrote the below code and not sure what's going wrong. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = ".....";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = this.responseText; 
        // here its not printing the responseText as expected.?????
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
console.log(xmlhttp.status);
console.log(xmlhttp.statusText);

function myFunction(arr) 
{
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        out += arr["results"].[i].name; // ????
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    document.write(out);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I have problem in two lines, as shown with question marks in the code and understand I am doing big mistakes. I am a beginner with web tech and would appreciate if any one can help me how to print the reponse text and store/print names from response when http response if of that format.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is an `Object` with two properties , first one is `results` that is array of objects, second is `meta` that is object.

Now you are trying to loop the array of objects hence the condition in the for loop must change to

`for(i = 0; i < arr.results.length; i++)`

Here we check the length of the Objects `results` property which is array of objects.

And to fetch each iterated object within the loop you must just use `[ ]` with index value.. right now you have an additional `.` which is not required.

`out += arr["results"][i].name;`

The `arr["results"]` will point to the array and `[i]` will access the object in the given index (value of i)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>

<script>
var responsetext = "{ \"results\":[ {\"name\":\"First\",\"venue\":{\"zip\":\"90405\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"desc\":\"1D\"}, {\"name\":\"Second\",\"venue\":{\"zip\":\"89065\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"desc\":\"2D\"}, {\"name\":\"Third\",\"venue\":{\"zip\":\"92352\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"desc\":\"3D\"} ], \"meta\":{\"next\":\"xxxx\",\"url\":\"yyyy\"}}";

var myArr = JSON.parse(responsetext);
myFunction(myArr);

function myFunction(arr) 
{
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.results.length; i++) 
    {
        out += arr.results[i].name;
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    document.write(out);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You need to reference `arr.results.length` (since the array is within the result key of the object), and furthermore it's `arr["results"][i].name`, or alternatively (better) `arr.results[i].name`.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you have to store names in an array.
store your http response in a variable myArr.

```
myFunction(myArr); //Out put in console ["First", "Second", "Third"]

function myFunction(arr) 
           {
               var resultarr = arr.results;
               var out = [];
               for(var i = 0; i < resultarr.length; i++) {
                   var obj = resultarr[i];
                   out.push(obj.name);
          }
          document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
         document.write(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple approach :**

**JSON :**

```
var Obj = {
  "results":[
             {"name":"First","venue":{"zip":"90405","country":"US"},"desc":"1D"},
             {"name":"Second","venue":{"zip":"89065","country":"US"},"desc":"2D"},
             {"name":"Third","venue":{"zip":"92352","country":"US"},"desc":"3D"}
            ],
  "meta":{"next":"xxxx","url":"yyyy"}
};
```

**Using Array map method :**

```
var result = Obj.results.map(function(a) {return a.name;});

console.log(result);
```

**Using for in loop :**

```
var arrayObj = [];

for (var i in Obj.results) {
  arrayObj.push(Obj.results[i].name);
}

console.log(arrayObj);
```

**Output :** **`["First", "Second", "Third"]`**